# drawable-land-xhdpi = invalid resource directory name?

Tags: android

My project's getting an error for drawable-land-xhdpi as an invalid resource directory name in the res/ folder. Anyone else have any ideas? I've had drawable-port-xhdpi sitting there just fine before, and it's only when I added in the drawable-land-xhdpi folder that the errors started happening.

Comment: Does it work for drawable-land-hdpi? or ldpi/mdpi?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the folder name and not it's content? Means: Does the error occur when the directory is completely empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bah. Eclipse did something extra weird with the directory names so it imported into the project named drawable-land-xhdpi, but the actual folder name was drawable-land-xdpi (missing the "h" in xhdpi).

Lesson to be learned: always look for typos.