# Android, Different drawable folders

Tags: android, drawable

Are we able to define **drawable** folders for `Landscape` and `portrait` screen as we are able to define for layers by defining `layout-land` ?

and even are we able to define screen mode (xhdpi , ...) and its rotation in a same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for example something like "drawable-land-xhdpi" should work fine.

References:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources
- [drawable-land-xhdpi = invalid resource directory name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597985/drawable-land-xhdpi-invalid-resource-directory-name)